# Как получить вектор с нужным capacity?

Tags: c++, vector

Может ли новосозданный вектор после вызова метода `reserve(x)` иметь `capacity` больше, чем `x`? Если да, то правда ли, что чтобы получить вектор с нужным тебе `capacity`, надо сначала заполнить вектор?

```
std::vector a;
a.reserve(x);
// ... insert x elements ...
a.shrink_to_fit();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Может ли новосозданный вектор после вызова метода reserve(x) иметь capacity больше, чем x?

да, ему некто это не запрещает

> Если да, то правда ли, что чтобы получить вектор с нужным тебе capacity, надо сначала заполнить вектор?

нет, не факт. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit

> It is a non-binding request to reduce capacity() to size(). It depends on the implementation whether the request is fulfilled.

может, но не обязан.

> Как получить вектор с нужным capacity?

а зачем? если это экономия памяти или что то ещё подобное, тогда может лучше свой вектор написать, который будет выделять "правильное" кол-во памяти. Если же это высоконагруженные приложения или embeded, где за каждый бит идет борьба, ответ тот же.

Comment: Можно вместо полного написания нового вектора как-то подкрутить настройки аллокатора, чтобы было 1 раз точное выделение `x`, а при превышении лимита исключение или UB?

Comment: а может Вам просто нужен std::array?

Comment: К сожалению, размер получаю извне, он не известен во время компиляции. А поведение надо как у `std::array`

Comment: тогда опишите задачу, зачем это могло понадобится.

Comment: Кажется, тут есть то, что надо, спасибо https://stackoverflow.com/q/55376433

Comment: Но только не забывайте, что если Вы выделяете память через malloc/new то не факт, что памяти будет выделено ровно столько, сколько Вы попросили. Ее часто выделяется чуточку больше. Иногда сильно чуточку больше.